# Trace all function from native library Android

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

i have an answer about the way to trace all functions from Native Library. For example, its name is "libexample.so". There are no results by when searching for this module `Process.findModuleByName("libexample.so")`.
That library dinamically loaded into the program and doesn't available from start.
The problem is that I need the very first function calls of this library. All I have is the address of that library, that i get while program runs.

How it could be done?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: The library has to be manually loaded by the Android app. Usually using Java calls such as `System.loadLibrary(..)` `ClassLoader.loadLibrary(..)` or `System.load(..)`.

Comment: @Robert, Yes, in my case it loaded by `Native.load(...)`.The order of actions is: `Native.load()` -> Call JNI functions defined in Java Class -> Calls of library's native functions.
I want to trace the last calls, but I have no idea how I can hook to them